# Converting Python list of lists to a MATLAB sparse matrix

Tags: python, list, matlab, sparse-matrix

I would like to convert a Python list of lists to a MATLAB sparse matrix. Each element of the Python list is a list with three elements: a row, a column, and a value. My code and the error message are below:

```
from __future__ import division
import matlab.engine

A = [[1,2,1],[1,3,1],[2,2,1]]
A = matlab.double(A)
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
eng.spconvert(A)
```

And the error message:

> ```
>  File "testMatlab.py", line 14, in <module>
>     eng.spconvert(A)
>   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matlab/engine/matlabengine.py", line 71, in __call__
>     _stderr, feval=True).result()
>   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matlab/engine/futureresult.py", line 67, in result
>     return self.__future.result(timeout)
>   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matlab/engine/fevalfuture.py", line 82, in result
>     self._result = pythonengine.getFEvalResult(self._future,self._nargout, None, out=self._out, err=self._err)
> TypeError: unsupported data type returned from MATLAB
> ```

The error goes away if we amend the code to, the problem is with Python not being able to handle the returned sparse matrix:

```
eng.spconvert(A,nargout=0)
```

Comment: If you need a sparse matrix in python use `scipy.sparse`. If you need it in matlab, you should build it in matlab, do whatever operations you need, and then pull it back out as a set of index & data arrays to python. Also, FWIW, I've never seen a python+matlab project that wasn't a giant train wreck.

Comment: @CJR Its easier to create the data from the regression in Python. To follow your suggestion, I'lll need to first write the data to disk, then upload it into matlab. I can do that but I'll save time if I can avoid going to disk

Comment: To be quite honest, I don't think you will. Writing a sparse matrix to an mtx file and reading it into matlab is unlikely to take much time and will take 30 seconds to write code for. Building a python to matlab sparse interface will take a lot of effort and you will gain almost nothing.